# Maximum nametable char count exceeded

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I'm having issues with the maximum nametable char count quota, I followed a couple of answers here and it solved the problem for a while, but now I'm having the same issue.

My Server side config is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="GenericBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None" />
          </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>
    <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                    <behavior>
                            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" />
                            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                            <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="1000000" />
                    </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
            <service name="REMWCF.RemWCFSvc">
              <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="REMWCF.IRemWCFSvc" bindingConfiguration="GenericBinding" />
              <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
              <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9081/RemWCFSvc" />
                </baseAddresses>
              </host>
            </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

I also have the same tcp binding on the devenv configuration.

Have I reached the limit of contracts supported? Is there a way to turn off that quota?

EDIT

Error Message:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from
>   net.tcp://localhost:9081/RemWCFSvc/mex If this is a Windows (R)
>   Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please
>   check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified
>   address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the
>   MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: net.tcp://localhost:9081/RemWCFSvc/mex    Metadata
>   contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'net.tcp://localhost:9081/RemWCFSvc/mex'.    There is an error in the
>   XML document.    The maximum nametable character count quota (16384)
>   has been exceeded while reading XML data. The nametable is a data
>   structure used to store strings encountered during XML processing -
>   long XML documents with non-repeating element names, attribute names
>   and attribute values may trigger this quota. This quota may be
>   increased by changing the MaxNameTableCharCount property on the
>   XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

I'm getting that error when trying to run the WCF (which is hosted in a windows service app).

Comment: As far as I know there are no limits to the size of messages. It is just at times rather tricky to configure correctly. What error message do you get?

Comment: I updated the question with the error.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct web config. You need to set the metadataenabled to be true and also you have not defined a behavior name. Try with this config.

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <bindings>
        <netTcpBinding>
          <binding name="GenericBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
                   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">

            <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                          maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
            <security mode="None" />
          </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
      </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>

    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
    <services>
            <service name="REMWCF.RemWCFSvc" behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication">
              <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="SilverlightWCFLargeDataApplication" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="REMWCF.IRemWCFSvc" bindingConfiguration="GenericBinding" />
                <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                  <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:9081/RemWCFSvc" />
                </baseAddresses>
              </host>
            </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```